# Loading up to 32768 Pictureboxes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a app which is loading between 32^2 to 32768  8x8 px pictureboxes. All pictureboxes are on screen so I need to load them all and can't just load some.

As it stands, my program won't even run. Is there a better way to load that many pictureboxes?

I would like to share with you my project, but I don't know how to.............

Thanks though!

Comment: You'll have to redesign some of your app's functionalities (your Users will appreciate it).

Comment: If you can explain how you planned to use all these controls, someone may suggest a better way.

Comment: You likely ought to be using GDI+ to draw `Images` directly on a control - either the form itself or maybe a single big `PictureBox`. As suggested, if you can explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it, then we may be able to suggest the best way.

Comment: Thinking this would work out is about as crazy as "I need to launch a million instances of my app but even time I try my computer slows to a crawl and eventually stops entirely". It feels like you're trying to show thousands of picture boxes so you can eg paint them different colors and make something that looks like an image, one pixel per box. Maybe you're trying to implement CHARMAP exe, one box per glyph. Do tell us more so we can give proper advice because in its current form this looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I suspect that [An Introduction to Creating a Tile Map Engine](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-creating-a-tile-map-engine--gamedev-10900) would start you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Here is a more detailed explanation to my project:

Comment: Ever heard of the program called TileLayerPro? Well, you see, I want to make a similar project like it but on the Sega Genesis VDP. I want to make many tiles and make myself be able to replace 1 tile with another tile. It's hard to explain though..........

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely run into a MemoryOverflowException with this design. From the sound of it, you're probably trying to render a map of some sort if that's the case then this answer is for you (otherwise just ignore it).

At a high level you should only create the number of PictureBox controls that can fit on the screen at any given time. You can calculate this with the following function:

```
Private Function CalculateSizeToFitParent(ByVal parent As Control, ByVal childSize As Size) As Size
    Return New Size(parent.Width \ childSize.Width, parent.Height \ childSize.Height)
End Sub
```

You would implement it as such to create a PictureBox to fill up the visible area of the current Form:

```
Dim pictureBoxSize As Size = New Size(8, 8)
Dim visibleArea(pictureBoxSize.Width - 1, pictureBoxSize.Height - 1) As PictureBox
Dim numberOfPictureBoxes As Size = CalculateSizeToFitParent(Me, pictureBoxSize)

For x As Integer = 0 To numberOfPictureBoxes.Width - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To numberOfPictureBoxes.Height - 1
        visibleArea(x, y) = New PictureBox() With {
            .Location = New Point(x * pictureBoxSize.Width, y * pictureBoxSize.Height)
            .Size = pictureBoxSize
        }
        Me.Controls.Add(visibleArea(x, y))
    Next
Next
```

The next part is two-fold:

1. You need to keep track of where the top-left corner of the current visible are is
2. You will need to reload the images in the respective visual area of the map.

This assumes that you have a 2D array that stores your images. And please note that you don't recreate the PictureBox controls but rather you just reload the image of the existing control:

```
Private _currentLocation As Point = New Point(0, 0) ' If you're starting somewhere else change it here
Public Property CurrentLocation As Point
    Get
        Return _currentLocation
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
        If (value <> _currentLocation) Then
            _currentLocation = value
            Me.OnCurrentLocationChanged()
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overridable Sub OnCurrentLocationChanged()
    RaiseEvent CurrentLocationChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Public Event CurrentLocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Private Sub MyForm_CurrentLocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.CurrentLocationChanged
    If (visibleArea Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New Exception("The visible area has not been generated yet.")
    End If
    If (_currentLocation Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New Exception("The CurrentLocation cannot be null.")
    End If

    Dim widthUpperBounds As Integer = My2DArrayOfImageLocations.GetUpperBounds(0) - 1
    Dim heightUpperBounds As Integer = My2DArrayOfImageLocations.GetUpperBounds(1) - 1
    For x As Integer = 0 To visibleArea.GetUpperBounds(0) - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To visibleArea.GetUpperBounds(1) - 1
            If (x + _currentLocation.Width > widthUpperBounds OrElse y + _currentLocation.Height) Then
                'This "block" is outside the view area (display a blank tile?)
            Else
                visibleArea(x, y).Load(My2DArrayOfImageLocations(x + _currentLocation.Width, y + _currentLocation.Height))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Now whenever you reset the CurrentLocation property (however you'd do that, e.g. arrow keys, asdw, etc.) it will redraw the visible area of the map.

**Update**
Please note that I "free-typed" this example and you may need to tweak it a bit. After some more thought, you'll probably also need to call the Refresh method of the PictureBox when you load in the image (I didn't test).